# PHP PDO with Oracle, call stored procedure when output parameter is a cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, pdo, cursor, output

i'm trying to use php with pdo. Is there any examples how to call oracle's stored procedure when the output parameter is a cursor?

I was able to do it using php with adodb and also oci8 extension

This is my stored procedure in Oracle

```
create or replace procedure   Search_Personal_Data
(   p_tipo_doc in Persona.TIPO_DOC%type, 
    p_nro_doc in  Persona.NRO_DOC%type,
    prc out sys_refcursor
)
AS
begin
   //some code
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO_OCI doesn't support REF CURSORS bind variables.

PDO is an abstraction layer so it doesn't have all the bells and whistles that native drivers like OCI8 have (although there has been some creep since the original PDO implementation).

You could convert the REF CURSOR to a PIPE, see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/converting-ref-cursor-to-pipe-for-performance-in-php-oci8-and-pdooci

Comment: Thanks Christopher, very helpful your answer.